# How can I make this command work and not give `Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"`

Tags: vim

This function works fine in neovim, but in vim 8 it gives error `E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h": %!pnpx prettier --stdin-filepath % --single-quote`

```
   "run global prettier install on current buffer
   func! Prettier_format()
       let save_cursor = getcurpos()
       exe '%!pnpx prettier --stdin-filepath % --single-quote'
       call setpos('.', save_cursor)
   endfunc

   nnoremap gp :call Prettier_format()<CR>
```

Comment: I guess you're working on a buffer without filename. Youcan first write the buffer to a file, then call your function. To prove it, you can `:echo @%` in your buffer.

Comment: Cheers! I am not sure why I can't work on a buffer without a filename? I modified the example from an answer that was slightly different and was upvoted as working. Could you show me how to write the buffer to a file and use that instead? I am totally new to vimscript!